# Android delete row with cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite, delete-row

I am creating a program in Android, on one of the screens I plan to iterate thought the rows in a database, presenting each row to the user and letting him skip it or delete it.

In Java I could user the *ResultSet*'s *deleteRow*() method, however android currently has no equivalent method. Or event a method to set a column with a mark for deletion.

Would doing the deletion via the *SQLiteDatabase* delete or executeSql method would the currently opened cursor remain valid and would the deleted row be removed from it?

If it becomes invalid what advise is there to not have to keep re-querying the database (or at least not recompile the statement each time)?

If the  cursor is still valid but not updated, would be the best way to ensure the user cannot return to this row?

Are there any better solutions to this problem?

Comment: Post some code you tried. Is really easy to remove when you have defined your sql helper and sql adapter. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Just build a list of item IDs to be deleted. Once the user operation is finished, you can delete the whole lot of them in a single step.

Comment: what would be the best way to store the ids so that if there is a power failier I can do the deletion when the program next starts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MatrixCursor to do this:

```
newCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {col1, col2, col3}); // col names
    mCursor.moveToPosition(-1); // your Cursor
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (<any condition>) {
            newCursor.addRow(indicationNames.rows(mCursor));

        }

    }
    mCursor = newCursor ;
```

By this way you have your cursor updated without affecting the database.

Comment: what is indicationNames here